# Why my depth map is so bad?

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I don't know if it's normal to obtain this kind of depth map ? Can you tell me ?

What I did is the following: i have dataset with left and right image. Thank to stereo_image_proc, I obtained the pointCloud2 and disparity image. (I can't know if my disparity image is valid because image_view crash and i can't see with rqt_image_view)

Then I transformed the Disparity Image to Depth Map thank to this node https://github.com/skohlbr/disparity_image_proc

But I obtain a very weird result: http://hpics.li/74b5c6f

Do you know why ? And especially how i can solve this problem ?

Many thank,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206826/why-my-depth-map-is-so-bad-?/) by [lilouch](https://answers.ros.org/users/21904/lilouch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2015-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't see what is weird about the result, closer points appear darker, while those further away are brighter, which is expected for depth images. Looks more like a visualization issue with image_view to me, as it does not set the min/max depth for coloring as you might would like. Not sure if there are command line options for doing so.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0